# Render external webpage in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js

it is possible in a view to render an external webpage from its url?I'm using backbone with handlebars.

```
var AuthorizeInstagramView = Backbone.View.extend({

    template: Handlebars.compile(template),


    initialize: function () {



    },



    render:function(){

        RENDER WEBPAGE FROM ITS URL
    },



  });

return AuthorizeInstagramView;

});
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Yeah, have it render an iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not make an AJAX call and output the response content? Like

```
render: function() {
    // Render the template here..

    // Then make the AJAX call and output the response content.
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET'
    }).done(function(response) {
        $("#content").html(response)
    });
}
```

Comment: I have pass response to render?